# Receive notification when site server adds page

Tags: url

I've been doing some programming off and on for my brother, who is a stock trader.  I'm wondering if it is possible to receive a push notification when a site server adds a page.  For example, the site smallcapfortunes.com frequently adds pages that are simple extensions off the main URL.  For example, the site regularly adds pages under URLs such as `/neca/`, `/stev/`, etc.

Are there existing methods to execute this?  Or is this something I need to write myself?  Has anyone here written anything like that?

I know there are existing sites to track basic updates to a single page.  In my research, though, I haven't found anything like this.

Please let me know if there are any other details I need to provide.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can only get a *push* notification if a specific website offers that service.

Some websites publish a [structured (XML) site map](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html).  If the one you're interested in does that, you could *pull* that sitemap on a regular basis and look for differences.

Answer (score 0):

you're most likely going to want to use http://scrapy.org/ to go through the site and find new /neca/ and /stev/ urls, etc, then just trigger the script every so often.